# Unable to login with core moqui framework

Tags: moqui

I have downloaded [source code](https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework/releases) (tar.gz) and performed the following steps:-

1. Download and unzip the binary distribution (Moqui-framework-2.1.0)
2. Run the command ./gradlew build
3. Run the command ./gradlew load
4. Run the command ./gradlew run

While accessing http://localhost:8080/Login, I am unable to login with username "john.doe" and password "moqui". Please help me out.

**Updates after David's comment**

Q. Which file, specifically, did you download?

I have downloaded the source code of Moqui Framework 2.1.0 https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework/archive/v2.1.0.tar.gz from this location https://github.com/moqui/moqui-framework/releases

Q. Which components do you have in place (in moqui/runtime/component)?

After build and load, there are no components in moqui/runtime/component

Q. What is does the log say when you try to login?

Here are the console log

`10:19:46.519  INFO 501263526-12                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit with ID [100002] in session [node013u20mscffg621wt9t56o2z7pi14]
10:19:46.616  INFO 501263526-12               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Transition Login/login in 96ms, redirecting to screen path URL: http://localhost:8080/vapps
10:19:46.626  INFO 501263526-18                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit with ID [100003] in session [node0cdyqv4opf27rn4usprflo0b15]
10:19:46.627  INFO 501263526-18               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Redirecting to /Login instead of rendering [vapps]
10:19:46.627  INFO 501263526-18               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl vapps [] in 1ms (text/html;charset=utf-8) session node0cdyqv4opf27rn4usprflo0b15
10:19:46.635  INFO 501263526-47                 o.m.i.c.UserFacadeImpl Created new Visit with ID [100004] in session [node0936j417vzo531glqmulxiqzgk16]
10:19:46.720  INFO oquiWorker-1          o.moqui.i.c.MessageFacadeImpl IP address not a IPv4 address
10:19:46.767  INFO 501263526-47               o.m.i.s.ScreenRenderImpl Login [] in 132ms (text/html;charset=utf-8) session node0936j417vzo531glqmulxiqzgk16`

Q. What happens in the browser?

When I press Sign In button after entering the username and password.
I have checked the browser console, I am getting 302 status for this URL
http://localhost:8080/Login/login

Comment: Which file, specifically, did you download? Which components to you have in place (in moqui/runtime/component)? What is does the log say when you try to login? What happens in the browser?

Comment: Hi David,

I have updated the question to answer your comments, please have a look into this.

Thanks!

Comment: Version 2.1.0 is very old (Oct, 22, 2017). I suggest you use current version. It can log in easy. I will support you log in if you checkout latest version.

Comment: @zatef , my email is `donhuvy@outlook.com` mobile `(++84) 346789542` Telegram `@vyhanoi` . You're welcome!